# WPF - How to restyle ComboBox to remove the textbox/editbox and replace with static text

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I want to restyle a WPF ComboBox which is formatted to be a drop-list type, BUT remove the selected TextBox which gets populated with the selected contents and just replace it with some static text and an image which remains constant, simulating a button like look.

So in effect it becomes a button-drop-list, so when I select an item from the drop list, I can populate another control via command bindings with its selected value and the button style remains.

Basically something like this crude picture I've hacked together.

[image: button drop-list]

I've seen examples of button with context menus, but I don't like the idea, and a ComboBox fits my needs perfectly in terms of function and easy command and data binding.

I know it can be done, but I lost faith in my ablity after reading overly confusing examples based on other controls. I couldn't find an example detailing my needs to learn from.

Cheers
DIGGIDY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much playing around, I decided the better option was to go for a button with bound context menu, this worked out to be the better solution in the end.

Thanks for your help Marc.

Comment: Is it not uggly? Did you try with a readonly EditBox above a ComboBox? The result looks exactly like your example. So bad that does not match your expectations. I am glad your context menu bounding does!

Comment: I found the combo didn't suit the overall look I was going for, but thanks for you help anyway, as I will more than likely use what I've learned here else where.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same problem and actually, it's simple.
Just put a read-only ComboBox with a SelectionChanged event.
You put in index 0 your static text.

Now, when the user is selecting something, get the selected item and then, set the SelectedIndex to 0. So you got the item the user selected but the displayed text is the same.

See:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (combo.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        // Do your stuff here...

        // Then
        combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice quick response. Almost there, but that means index 0 is also included in the drop list, is there a way of doing it without adding into the list?

Comment: Yes it's included but if you select it, nothing will happen. As a cancel option. Currently I don't see any other answer, but I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: I'm thinking I could change it's visiblity with a xmal data trigger, I'm having a play with rather limited knowledge of wpf/xaml to see if I can do this as well, then I will have a workable solution

Comment: See my other answer, I think it will match your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** According to me, I prefer my previous answer. So make sure you, reader, that my previous answer doesn't match your expectations. **[/EDIT]**

Another answer is to put your object above the ComboBox and then catch the MouseDown event from this object and dropped down the ComboBox. I used a read-only TextBox in my example.

See:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Combo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="TEST" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="TEST1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="TEST2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="TEST3" />
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseDown"/>
</Grid>
```

And then the code behind:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true; // Prevents the event.
    Combo.IsDropDownOpen = true; // Drops down the ComboBox.
}
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: I did it with Microsoft Visual Studio Designer, so make sure the two components are exactly at the same emplacement.